# How to send custom data beween parent and child akka actor?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

Below code :

```
package playground

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, _}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

case object ReplyMessage
case object StopMessage
case object LinRMessage
case object LinRMessageChild

case class ListData(data : List[String])

class ModelParent(child: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  val logger = com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger("ModelParent")

  def receive = {

    case ListData =>
      logger.info("Got reply in Parent")
    case LinRMessage =>
      child ! LinRMessageChild
    case _ => println("Parent got something unexpected.")
  }
}

class ModelChild extends Actor {
  val logger = com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger("ModelChild")

  def receive = {
    case LinRMessageChild =>
      logger.info("Received LinRMessage")
      //sender ! ReplyMessage
      val l = List("1" , "2" , "3")
      sender ! ListData(l)
    case StopMessage =>
      println("Received Stop Message")
      context.stop(self)
    case _ => println("Child got something unexpected.")
  }
}

object ModelsDriver {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val system = ActorSystem("sys")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)

    val modelChild = system.actorOf(Props[ModelChild], name = "modelChild")
    val modelParent = system.actorOf(Props(new ModelParent(modelChild)), name = "modelParent")

    modelParent ! LinRMessage
    modelParent ! LinRMessage
    modelParent ! LinRMessage

  }

}
```

prints to console :

```
22:08:55.807 [sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO ModelChild - Received LinRMessage
22:08:55.810 [sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO ModelChild - Received LinRMessage
22:08:55.810 [sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO ModelChild - Received LinRMessage
Parent got something unexpected.
Parent got something unexpected.
Parent got something unexpected.
```

Here is causing the `Parent got something unexpected.` output :

```
case _ => println("Parent got something unexpected.")
```

I'm attempting to return a List of Strings from the child to the parent actor of type :

```
case class ListData(data : List[String])
```

This populates the return data :

```
  val l = List("1" , "2" , "3")
  sender ! ListData(l)
```

But as error indicates I'm not sending the data correctly. How to send data within message between a parent and child actor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to these lines in your parent actor:

```
case ListData =>
  logger.info("Got reply in Parent")
```

Normally, you'd want to pattern match and extract the contents of the case class like so:

```
case ListData(l: List[String]) =>
  logger.info("Got reply in Parent")
```

Where you'd be able to access the contents as `l`.

Since in your example, you aren't really doing anything with the contents, you could do one of the following as well:

```
case ListData(_) =>
  logger.info("Got reply in Parent")
```

or:

```
case _: ListData =>
  logger.info("Got reply in Parent")
```

Answer (score 3):

When we define a case class

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
```

the compiler also automatically defines the corresponding companion singleton object

```
object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo(x)
  def unapply(v: Foo): Option[Foo] = ...
}
```

Hence the function

```
val recieve: Any => String = {
  case Foo    => "I am companion singleton object of Foo"
  case Foo(_) => "I am instance of Foo case class"
}

recieve(Foo)
recieve(Foo(42))
```

outputs

```
res0: String = I am companion singleton object of Foo
res1: String = I am instance of Foo case class
```

where we see

```
case Foo => "I am companion singleton object of Foo"
```

matches on the automatically generated companion singleton object.

Similarly,

```
val recieve: Any => String = {
  case _: Foo.type => "I am companion singleton object of Foo"
  case _: Foo      => "I am instance of Foo case class"
}

recieve(Foo)
recieve(Foo(42))
```

outputs

```
res0: String = I am companion singleton object of Foo
res1: String = I am instance of Foo case class
```

because they type of singleton object `Foo` is `Foo.type`, whilst the type of the instance `Foo(42)` is `Foo`. Also consider

```
val a: Foo = Foo(42)
val b: Foo.type = Foo
```

This logic error was introduced due to the presence of `Any` in `Any => Unit`. On the other hand, `Foo => Unit` would catch the error at compile time

```
val recieve: Foo => Unit = {
  case Foo =>  // compiler error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type
}
```

Comment: Re the last note about `Any => Unit`, Akka Typed fixes that, though it's a bit of an adjustment to go from `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` to `Function[T, Behavior[T]]`